# EC2 P2 instance : keep data in GPU memory for realtime processing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cuda, gpu, gpgpu

I have a GPU app (C++ web service). During the initialization of the web service, I load around 20,000 images from S3, perform some image-processing tasks and store results in GPU memory.(~$4Gb of data).

Then the web service keeps running on EC2 waiting for user requests.

Next user requests use this data to perform some "near-realtime" tasks(using CUDA) and return the result back to the user.

My question is, can I keep this amount of data in GPU memory? Is it possible that GPU memory (or EC2 instance) get restarted/refresh?

**Update**
I will be using a P2 instance(~2000 CUDA cores) running Ubuntu 18. Total GPU memory is 16G so it has enough free memory.  I tested my code on my desktop with old GTX card with 340 CUDA cores and 4GB memory and I get the result in about 4seconds. I assume on P2 instance result will be near real-time(~1sec). And one of my requirement is that, this web-service will be called around 30 times per minute. Hopefully, this won't cause high load on the GPU.

Comment: we need more details:  is your web service expected to scale when there is high demand?  or is one instance of the web service running per user request?

Comment: wondering why this has downvotes? why this isnt a valid question?

Comment: @RobertCrovella not true - reserved instances is an AWS billing discount, not a specific instance to call your own.  See first paragraph here: 
 https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-reserved-instances.html

Comment: It seems Robert deleted his comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Robert's comment is spot on. You can (and should) store your 4GB of data in the GPU during some initialization function. When/where that function gets called is up to the architecture of your web service and how persistent it is. I'm not familiar with AWS, but I would guess that if the instance goes down or gets restarted, your C++ application is no longer running, which means any pointers to device memory are gone. That said, I would guess that restarts are not very common events, so you should be OK with just loading GPU memory once when the instance (and your app) get started.

You don't mention which of the many CUDA memory APIs you are using, but I would recommend to do a manual `cudaMemcpy()` to move the data to a known location on the device. Then you should just have a reusable device pointer to the data each time you have to do your computation.

Comment: downvoted because your answer and Robert's comments allude to instances not being rebooted.  A responsible answer should advise the OP to safeguard against instance reboots - they happen.  See EC2 maintenance page: https://aws.amazon.com/maintenance-help/ .  AWS console even has a built in a scheduled event console for user notification:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-instances-status-check_sched.html.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is a Linux instance.

Your requirement is not difficult to achieve. 4 GB of memory is small today for enterprise class systems.

1) Turn off swap.

2) Make sure that you have extra free memory once the 4 GB is allocated.

3) Design your application to use shared memory and lock the pages which will guarantee your objects stay in memory.

4) Design your application to handle system reboots. Rarely, but it does happen, AWS will do maintenance on a cluster and your instance will get moved / rebooted.

Comment: thank you for the reply. Yes, I will be using a P2 instance(~2000 CUDA cores) running Ubuntu 18. Total GPU memory is 16G so it has enough free memory.  I tested my code on my desktop with old GTX card with 340 CUDA cores and 4GB memory and I get the result in about 4seconds. I assume on P2 instance result will be near real-time(~1sec). And one of my requirement is that, this web-service will be called around 30 times per minute. Hopefully, this won't be high load on the GPU.

Comment: I don't see what any of this has to do with keeping data in *GPU* memory

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible that GPU memory (or EC2 instance) get
>   restarted/refresh?

**Yes**, because AWS is constantly upgrading instances and servers to stay up to date and help ensure security, you can bet that your instance will be restarted.  These are not daily, but to say they are "not common" is not true.  Anticipate once or twice a year frequencies.

You can safeguard against this by designing in a maintenance mode for your Web Service to respond with "Temporarily Down for Maintenance" or something similar during the reboots.  You can even perform the instance reboots proactively if you like to minimize the impact.

You can get the full details of instance and server reboots from the [EC2 Maintenance Page](https://aws.amazon.com/maintenance-help/)

Ultimately if you stay on AWS, you will want to redesign your application to take advantage of more than just S3 and EC2.  There are AWS features to ensure high availability during planned (or unplanned) maintenance.  These are all designed to remove risks from your endeavor and maximize your online uptime.  To list them all in one answer would be impossible.  It is a long list and constantly growing.

To give you an idea:  Take a look at some of the [example reference architectures at the bottom of this page](https://aws.amazon.com/architecture/) to give you an idea of what is possible and recommended.  Also some of the [AWS White Papers](https://media.amazonwebservices.com/AWS_Building_Fault_Tolerant_Applications.pdf) or [blog posts](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/building-powerful-web-applications-in-the-aws-cloud-a-love-story/) can help guide you to improve your hosted web application.

Don't expect to just migrate your service to AWS and not make changes to it.  To maximize AWS value (or any cloud provider) and lower risk, you will need to learn the services offered and redesign your service to best take advantage of these.  They are changing every year.